# Same method and constant name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scoping

```
module Demo  
  Myconstant = 'This is the constant'
  private
    def Myconstant
      puts 'This is the method'
    end
end

class Sample
  include Demo

  def test
    puts Myconstant # => 'This is the constant'
  end

end

Sample.new.test
```

How does the snippet above work?

Shouldn't `Myconstant` the method overwrite the "true" constant?

Is there a way to call the method instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses to explicitly call the method:

```
puts Myconstant
#⇒ 'This is the constant'

puts Myconstant()
#⇒ 'This is the method'
```

Comment: Right. So Ruby can have the same name referring to two different things  as long as they are two different things... is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Variables and methods live in different namespaces. When there is an ambiguity, Ruby chooses the variable. If you want the method instead, you need to make it un-ambiguos. Two ways to do that, are an explicit receiver (`self.foo`) or an argument list (`foo()`), since a variable can have neither.